# How to properly update a global variable in python using lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which each row shows one transaction and items within that transactions. Here is how my dataframe looks like

```
itemList
A,B,C
B,F
G,A
...
```

I want to find the frequency of each item (how many times it appeared in the transactions. I have defined a dictionary and try to update its value as shown below

```
dict ={}
def update(itemList):
   #Update the value of each item in the dict

df.itemList.apply(lambda x: update(x))
```

As `apply` function gets executed for multiple row at the same time, multiple rows try to update the values in `dict` at the same time and it's causing an issue. How can I make sure multiple updated to `dict` does not cause any issue?

Comment: Why do you think *multiple rows try .. at the same time*? `apply` is just a for loop.

Comment: As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) article, please provide a reproducible sample. By this I mean: a sample dataset we can copy/paste, the output of what you are getting, and a sample of what you want to have as output.

Comment: You don't need a lambda expression anymore. `df.itemList.apply(update)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df['itemList'].str.get_dummies(',').sum().to_dict()
#{'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'F': 1, 'G': 1}
```

---

If there are more columns use:

```
df.stack().str.get_dummies(',').sum().to_dict()
```

---

if you want to count for each row:

```
df['itemList'].str.get_dummies(',').to_dict('index')
#{0: {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'F': 0, 'G': 0},
# 1: {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 0, 'F': 1, 'G': 0},
# 2: {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'F': 0, 'G': 1}}
```

As @Quang Hoang said in the comments `apply` simply apply the function to each row / column using a loop

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off relying on native python here,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'itemlist':['a,b,c', 'b,f', 'g,a', 'd,g,f,d,s,a,v', 'e,w,d,f,g,h', 's,d,f,e,r,t', 'e,d,f,g,r,r','s,d,f']})
```

Here is a solution using Counter,

```
df['itemlist'].str.replace(',','').apply(lambda x: Counter(x)).sum()
```

Some comparisons,

```
%timeit df['itemlist'].str.split(',', expand = True).stack().value_counts().to_dict()
2.64 ms ± 99.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['itemlist'].str.get_dummies(',').sum().to_dict()
3.22 ms ± 68.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

from collections import Counter
%timeit df['itemlist'].str.replace(',','').apply(lambda x: Counter(x)).sum()
778 µs ± 12.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```